# Change table columns order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I need to change the order of columns in a table in html / js dynamically, you can tell me how to do it?

Comment: changing columns is tough, changing rows is easy

Comment: Use a table plugin. http://plugins.jquery.com/projects/plugins/tables

Comment: You should give more details here. Are you hoping to allow users to drag and drop the order of columns? How flexible do you need this to be?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you only require to simply move a column without any fancy drag-drop animation, the following JS should do the trick:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        jQuery.each($("table tr"), function() { 
            $(this).children(":eq(1)").after($(this).children(":eq(0)"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

*Replacing the numbers as necessary. The concept works*

It seems that writing this as a one liner isn't really possible. including td in the selector, even with the row selector seems to hold *each td* on a separate index, ignoring rows.

A jQuery grid plugin should do the trick otherwise. Although I have no experience with such plugins.

Comment: Hmm.. not to knock this answer, but why the switch of correct answer? I'd give mine the edge for re-usability.

Comment: this is not bad, just be aware it won't work if there are merged cells (ie: rowspan > 1)

Comment: I made a minor change to this one, rather then using a selector in the children, it's much easier to chain .eq(1) for example.  This makes it easier to pass in arguments :)

Comment: What will be equivalent code in plain javascript for this

Answer (score 38):

Moving columns is not that hard:

You can use this function:

```
jQuery.moveColumn = function (table, from, to) {
    var rows = jQuery('tr', table);
    var cols;
    rows.each(function() {
        cols = jQuery(this).children('th, td');
        cols.eq(from).detach().insertBefore(cols.eq(to));
    });
}
```

Then invoke it like so:

```
var tbl = jQuery('table');
jQuery.moveColumn(tbl, 2, 0);
```

So, by knowing the index of the column, and the index of where you'd like to put it (zero-based), you can move the columns, including column headings.

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qsys7/1/

Comment: as other solutions, might be enough, but it doesn't work with merged cells (ie rowspan > 1)

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work when I try to do a tbl,0,6 (move the first column to the last place). Instead i'm obliged to do 1,0 => 2,1 => 3,2 ... 6,5 to put the first column at the lastp lace

Comment: Modified your code to allow moving the columns to the last column. See: http://jsfiddle.net/fyq9em36/

Comment: Only seems to work when moving from right to left.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a jQuery plugin I just wrote to switch the contents of two columns:

```
$.fn.switchColumns = function ( col1, col2 ) {
    var $this = this,
        $tr = $this.find('tr');

    $tr.each(function(i, ele){
        var $ele = $(ele),
            $td = $ele.find('td'),
            $tdt;

        $tdt = $td.eq( col1 ).clone();
        $td.eq( col1 ).html( $td.eq( col2 ).html() );
        $td.eq( col2 ).html( $tdt.html() );
    });
};
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/HGMxM/1/)

Comment: Tried this, it actually only switches the contents of the cells not the columns themselves.  This doesn't work if you have the td elements are important to the content contained within them.  Concept works though if you don't have those requirements.

Comment: Moving contents of columns is not so clever if you have `width` property or other styling properties on the columns.  You just end up with the wide-column being much narrower, and vice-versa.

Comment: Helpful answer +1. Work for me

Answer (score 0):

**Change columns by name**
A | B | C
C | A | B

```js
var new_table = [
    {
        name: "Column C",
        index: 0, // actual index
        cols: []
    },
    {
        name: "Column A",
        index: 0,
        cols: []
    },
    {
        name: "Column B",
        index: 0,
        cols: []
    },
]

jQuery.moveColumn = function (table, from, to) {
    var list_th = jQuery('th', table);
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(list_th).length-2; i++) {
        list_th[i];
        new_table.find(e => e.name == list_th[i].textContent).index = i
    }
    console.log("Add actual index", new_table);

    var rows = jQuery('tr', table);
    var num_rows = Object.keys(rows).length-2
    console.log(num_rows);

    for (let j = 0; j < num_rows; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < Object.keys(list_th).length-2; k++) {
            new_table.find(e => e.index == k).cols.push(jQuery(rows[j]).children()[k])
        }
        jQuery(rows[j]).empty("td");
        new_table.forEach(e => {
            jQuery(rows[j]).append(e.cols[j])
        });
    }
    console.log("Add cols", new_table);
}

var tbl = jQuery('table');
jQuery.moveColumn(tbl);
```

Exemple: http://jsfiddle.net/hw3nmeqb/