# Sort and toggle table columns with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I would like to enable user to choose which columns in table are visible, and it what order.

How can I mix sortable/draggable or other plugins to achieve this? Any help would be great.

It would be nice if user settings could be saved and re-read with jQuery cookie plugin, which I use.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464219/change-table-columns-order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem like this:

Make a form with checkboxes of available columns, and make form fields sortable.

After a form submit I have clear list of columns to display along with order.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few different jQuery plugins for this, one quick search revealed http://tablesorter.com/docs/ which has quite a few samples.

See the complete list at http://plugins.jquery.com/

Comment: There's also http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=5 . It doesn't quite cover toggling columns.