# CSS3 - Is there way to add some column filters?

Tags: javascript, html, css, protractor

I want to add some column filters in order to allow to filter a data in some html report,
but i don't have a friendly access to the html generator,
so my easy way is to do it by to add some hack inside the external css of this report.

Any ideas guys?

**The HTML report generator:**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

**The HTML report (actual view):**

[image]

**CSS:**

```
body{
    font-family:Arial
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px #D0D0D0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
}

h1:after {
    content: " - vCita Production \a";
    white-space: pre;
}

div {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul,li{
    margin-left:0;
    padding-left:0;
    width:100%;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

table{
    width:95%;text-align:left;
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse: separate;
    margin-bottom:5px;

}

body > ul {
  margin: 0 30px;
}

li{
    font-weight:bold;
    list-style:none;
    width: 1900px;
    width:100% !important;
}

ul table li{
    font-weight: normal;
}

th {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

td {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
}
td:hover {
    background: #F0F0F0;
}

a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

td.desc-col{
    width:500px;
}

th.desc-col{
    width: 500px;
}

td.status-col{
    width:75px;
}

th.status-col{
    width: 75px;
}

td.browser-col{
    width:160px;
}

th.browser-col{
    width: 160px;
}

td.os-col{
    width:100px;
}

th.os-col{
    width: 100px;
}

th.img-col{
    width: 50px;
}

td.img-col{
    width: 80px;
}

th.msg-col{
    width: 200px;
}

td.msg-col{
    width: 200px;
    word-break: break-all;
    display: inline-block !important;
}


table.header{
    background-color: gray;
     color: #fff;
     margin-left:30px;
}

.traceinfo{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right:0;
     background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
     z-index: 99999;opacity:0;
     -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
     transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
     pointer-events: none;

}

.traceinfo.visible{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.traceinfo > div{
    width: 800px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10% auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 75%;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.traceinfo .close{
    background: #606061;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -10px;
    width: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.traceinfo .close:hover{
    background: #00d9ff;
}

img.alt{
src: url(http://idantesting.comuv.com/public_html/reports/);
}
```

Comment: if it has an external JS, that would work, but CSS alone not so much

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately you cant do this with css, you'll need a javascript solution.

Whilst it's possible to write it from scratch it a bigger job then you might imagine, but there are several plugins you can use, such as:

[list.js](http://www.listjs.com/examples/table) - has functionalty to sort tables as well as lists

[watable](http://wootapa-watable.appspot.com/) - requires jquery but provides lots of functionality

If you really want to write something from scratch you could look at this SO question on a [jquery sorter for rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464219/change-table-columns-order)

As you are using a node package to generate the report, there isnts (to my knowledge) a way to add custom javascriot the same way you can add custom css. One option would be to use grunt to run the report, then use a template/find/replace to insert the javascript code `<script src="[some url">` into the html that's been rendered

Comment: Thanks, this is the report generator i used:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter

@atmd do you have any idea how can i call this JS by this service?

Comment: you could use grunt after the html has been rendered. updated my answer to include

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later on and update you about the results.