# Order the Fields when display on view in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am displaying data but fields are in dynamic order that is changed every time it's displayed.

Now I reorder the fields by a multiselect dropdown that reorders the field fine. The problem is that I want to display data of reordered field. How is it possible?

My code

```
@foreach (var student in Model.List)
{
   <tr>
      <td> @List.No</td>
      <td> @List.Name  </td>
      <td> @List.Mobile</td>                   
   </tr>
}
```

It displays fields data only if i write manually in view site. but if i select order

e.g

```
 No Name  Mobile
    1 Ajay 777777777
    2 Vijay 8888888888
    3 Sanjay 888888888
```

or

```
  Name   No Mobile
     Ajay   1 777777777
     Vijay  2 8888888888
     Sanjay 3 888888888
```

or

```
 Mobile     Name   No 
    777777777  Ajay   1 
    8888888888 Vijay  2 
    888888888  Sanjay 3
```

then how it's possible to display?

Comment: Show code of `InvoiceList` ?

Comment: its list of student data.

Comment: Please make your question more organized like what you did, what you need etc.

Comment: Try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464219/change-table-columns-order