# Index Column Position

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How to fix a "Pandas Data Frame" at which,

"Index Column" set to be shown at the **Right** hand side of the others,

instead of the default left one.

Answer (score 0):

approaches

- drop the index and `concat()` to RHS
- add javascript to `to_html()` that moves   attributes [change column order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464219/change-table-columns-order). This doesn't work well with jupyter as javascript is not executed

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"idxcol":["A","B","C"], "idxcol2":["N","M","N"],"col2":[1,2,3]}).set_index(["idxcol","idxcol2"])
dfr = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), pd.Series(df.index.values)], axis=1).rename(columns={0:"-".join(df.index.names)})

print(df.to_markdown())
print(dfr.to_markdown())
```

#### before

```
                col2
idxcol idxcol2      
A      N           1
B      M           2
C      N           3
```

#### after

```
   col2 idxcol-idxcol2
0     1         (A, N)
1     2         (B, M)
2     3         (C, N)
```